# Microchip : Struct array, wrong memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, struct, microchip, mplab

On Mplab IDE, with a PIC24, C99 language,
I have built an array of structures :

```
typedef struct{
    enum GPRS_code_state        src_state;
    enum GPRS_code_return       ret_code;
    enum GPRS_code_state        dst_state;
}Transition;

Transition GPRS_transitions[] = {
        {GPRS_CIPSHUT       , GPRS_retour_ok    , GPRS_CIPSHUT_rep  },
        {GPRS_CIPSHUT       , GPRS_retour_repeat, GPRS_CIPSHUT      },
        {GPRS_CIPSHUT       , GPRS_retour_timeout, GPRS_Error       },
..................................}
```

When initializing the array, the first element (zero) is correctly allocated.
But all others aren't written after the first one in the memory.

The debugger is trying to show me the array at the beggining of the memory but the content is wrong.
I've tried to change the place of initialization unsuccessfully.

This code is perfectly working on a computer.

Any idea ?

Comment: Assuming the constants are correct, I do not see a problem. Maybe it's the toolchain. I'd check for erratas.

Comment: dspic24E and a controller with more than 32kb ram? Do the initialization in code. Loading of structured constants in expressions with __eds__ references go wrong iirc.